# Conditionally adding properties to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Is there a more concise or readable way of doing this?

```
var foo={a:111,c:333, somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded:'xxx'};
var myobj={x:1,y:2,z:3};
if(foo.a){myobj.a=foo.a;}
if(foo.b){myobj.b=foo.b;}
if(foo.c){myobj.c=foo.c;}
```

EDIT.  Context why I am doing this is below.

```
var obj={value:this.text,css:{color:'#929292',margin:'1px 0px'}};
if(this.width){obj.css.width=this.width;}
if(this.type){obj.type=this.type;}
if(this.id){obj.id=this.id;}
var input=$('<input/>',obj)
```

Comment: `jquery.extend(myobj, foo)`

Comment: @hindmost  `somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded` might pose a problem.

Comment: @user1032531 Could `delete myobj.somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded` afterwards?

Comment: @RGraham  Guess the right answer, like always, depends on the actual circumstances.  Do I have a bunch of properties to add and only one or two which shouldn't be, or the opposite.

Comment: @hindmost  `extend()` looks like a good solution if some sort of filter could be applied to the `foo` to only return the applicable properties to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple loop-based approach:

```
var foo={a:111,c:333, somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded:'xxx'};
var myobj={x:1,y:2,z:3};

['a','b','c'].forEach(function(key) {
    if(key in foo) {
        myobj[key] = foo[key];
    }
});
```

Notice how I used the `in` keyword. Your current solution will not work if the value of a property is (e.g.) `false` or `0`.

*Additionaly, to get better solutions, provide some context: why are you conditionally copying properties? Perhaps you can avoid this to begin with.*

Comment: Context provided to original post.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of the spread operator in ES2018 you can do something like this.

```
const original = {
    first: null,
    second: 'truthy'
};

const conditionalObject = {
  ...( original.first && { first: original.first }),
  ...( original.second && { second: original.second })
};
```

In the `conditionalObject` we first check if the property we want to add from the `original` is truthy, if it is we spread that property with its value into the new object.

If the property from the original object is falsy, the `&&` short circuits and the property is never spread into the new object.

You can read a more detailed explanation [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-conditionally-build-an-object-in-javascript-with-es6-e2c49022c448)

The new `conditionalObject` will look like this

```
{
    second: 'truthy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator like this:

```
myobj.a = foo.a ? foo.a : undefined;
```

Though its not exactly the same as the if statement you have, because you'll have `{a: undefined}` instead of `{}`. The difference would show up if you ever enumerated the keys of your object.

**Edit:**

@hindmost has a good suggestion in the comments. You could improve it further with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
_.extend(myobj, _.pick(foo, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Comment: Btw underscore also provides a function `_.omit` what will be the opposite of `_.pick`

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `extend`, then `delete` the properties you don't want:

```
function extendExcept(sourceObject, targetObject, except) {
    var target = $.extend(sourceObject, targetObject);
    except.forEach(function(key) {
        delete target[key];
    });
    return target;
}
```

You could call it like:

```
var foo={a:111,c:333, somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded:'xxx'};
var myobj={x:1,y:2,z:3};
myobj = extendExcept(foo, myobj, ["somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded"]);
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j361x52d/)

Comment: But what is the `except` property all ready exists on `sourceObject`?

Comment: @dev-null Valid point. I guess this depends on the requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = {
    a: 111, 
    c: 333, 
    somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded: 'xxx'
}; 

var myObj = {
    x: 1, 
    y: 2, 
    z: 3
}; 

for(var key in foo) {
    if(key === 'somePropertyThatShouldntBeAdded') {
        continue; 
    }
    myObj[key] = foo[key]; 
}
```